# Regex replace c# html

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, regex

I'm trying to do a regex replace on some HTML content, and what I need to do is append a URL parameter to the URL that is already there for tags such as anchor tags, link tags, etc. So for example, if I have an anchor tag such as

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">test</a>
```

it should become (attached with a '?')

```
<a href="http://www.google.com?append=1">test</a>
```

But if there is a url parameter already, it should just append it - so, this:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com?s=this&q=test">test</a>
```

will become (attached with a '&')

```
<a href="http://www.google.com?s=this&q=test&append=1">test</a>
```

I also have to consider that sometimes there may not necessarily be a link always - such as

```
<a href="javascript:doThis('test')">test</a>
```

In this case, I have to leave it alone.

There may also be a link embedded in javascript, such as:

```
<a href="javascript:doThis('http://www.google.com')">test</a> 
<a href="javascript:window.open('newWindow','http://www.google.com')">test</a>
```

This should get replaced as well like this (with a '&' or '?'):

```
<a href="javascript:doThis('http://www.google.com?append=1')">test</a> 
<a href="javascript:window.open('newWindow','http://www.google.com?append=1')">test</a>
```

(this one is not so important - I can live without this)

Also, the links may not always have http:// - it could be just a relative link:

```
<a href="/home.aspx?s=this&q=test">test</a>
```

It should just append like before:

```
<a href="/home.aspx?s=this&q=test&append=1">test</a>
```

I tried the following - the first one replaced all the javascript links as well, and any other links (not real URLs). And the second one isn't working at all...

```
    content = Regex.Replace(content, "href=\"(.*)\\?(.*)\"", "href=\"$1?append=1&$2\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    content = Regex.Replace(content, "href=\"([^?]*)\"", "href=\"$1?append=2\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

**EDIT:** I've tried using HTML Agility pack already, its just that that HTML I am getting is not well formed, so it won't work. Also, the HTML I am getting is not a one liner, its a whole page that I have to do this for...

Comment: Can you use the Uri class? Use it to parse the link, then do whatever you want with it.

Comment: How do I do that? I first need to find the link, no?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you start of by using [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). I could be wrong, but it looks like you are using regular expressions to determine the anchor tags? I'd say that is probably not the best idea and possibly overcomplicates things.

You should be able to get all anchor tags, then get the href from them like this example from the docs:

> For example, here is how you would fix all hrefs in an HTML file:
>
> ```
>  HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
>  doc.Load("file.htm");
>  foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
>  {
>     HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
>     att.Value = FixLink(att);
>  }
>  doc.Save("file.htm");
> ```

Of course that doesn't solve your issue exactly, but you get the idea. Overall I think it is a better approach that trying to use regex for everything.

Comment: Unfortunately, the HTML I am getting (not under my control) is not properly formed, so the HTML parsing fails with the agility pack.

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means robust, and I would not really suggest trying to do it this way, but if you want to try to do it with just regex and string replacing:

```
string source = "your html tag here";
string href = Regex.Match(source, "href=\".*\"").Value.Replace("\"", "").Replace("href=", "");
string url;
string toReplace;
bool tryToAppend = true;

if(href.Contains("'"))
{
    //if the href contains something else in quotes then its probably javascript
    //only capture something in quotes if it has a . (assume this means a url)
    url = Regex.Match(href, @"'.*\..*'").Value.Replace("'", "");

    //if we didnt find something in javascript with a . then abort
    if (url.Length == 0) 
    {
        tryToAppend = false;
    }
    toReplace = url;
}
else
{
    url = href;
    toReplace = url;
}

if (tryToAppend)
{
    if (url.Contains("?"))
    {
        url += "&append=1";
    }
    else
    {
        url += "?append=1";
    }

    source = source.Replace(toReplace, url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This first regex should work on all double quote delimited hrefs. It will ignore any hrefs that begin with javascript:. It covers only your main scenarios, but it is simple.

```
(href="(?!javascript:)[^"?]+)(?:(\?[^&"]+)(&[^"]+)?)?"
```

You get three capture groups:

- Group 1: The beginning of the match from the word HREF to the URL's file name (just before the `?` if there is one). `Example: href="http://www.google.com`
- Group 2: The ? and the first parameter of the querystring. `Example: ?append=1`
- Group 3: The first & and everything that follows it. `Example: &q=test&append=1`

By checking if capture groups 2 and/or 3 have values, you can determine if you need to append your parameters with a `?` or a `&`. Of your examples anchors, the following are matched and have the following values in their capture groups.

```
 Example 1:  
   href="http://www.google.com
 Example 2:  
   href="http://www.google.com ?append=1
 Example 3:  
   href="http://www.google.com ?s=this     &q=test
 Example 4:  
   href="http://www.google.com ?s=this     &q=test&append=1
 Example 10: 
   href="/home.aspx            ?s=this     &q=test
 Example 11: 
   href="/home.aspx            ?s=this     &q=test&append=1
```

I tried to write a regex that covers the above scenarios and the additional ones for the paths inside javascript HREFs. It seems to work, but it's not what I would call pretty. To keep it as simple as possible I made the following assumptions:

- The HREF value is double quote delimited.
- The URL inside the javascript function parameters is absolute and starts with http://.

The regex has the same capture groups as listed above.

```
(href="(?:javascript:[^\(]+\([^\)]*?http://[^"?\)]+|(?!javascript:)[^"?]+))(?:(\?[^&'"]+)(&[^"']+)?)?(?:'\))?"
```

Again, of your examples anchors, the following are matched and have the following values in their capture groups.

```
 Example 1:  
   href="http://www.google.com
 Example 2:  
   href="http://www.google.com                                     ?append=1
 Example 3:  
   href="http://www.google.com                                     ?s=this     &q=test
 Example 4:  
   href="http://www.google.com                                     ?s=this     &q=test&append=1
 Example 6:  
   href="javascript:doThis('http://www.google.com
 Example 7:  
   href="javascript:window.open('newWindow','http://www.google.com
 Example 8:  
   href="javascript:doThis('http://www.google.com                  ?append=1
 Example 9:  
   href="javascript:window.open('newWindow','http://www.google.com ?append=1
 Example 10: 
   href="/home.aspx                                                ?s=this     &q=test
 Example 11: 
   href="/home.aspx                                                ?s=this     &q=test&append=1
```